# How to always navigate to the initial route of the stack on back button press of any screen of the stack?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I have bottom navigator like below

```
 <DirectStack.Navigator screenOptions={appStackScreenOption}>
      <DirectStack.Screen name="CList" component={CList}
        options={(navigation) => ({
          headerRight: () => (
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>{AddListButton(navigation)}</View>
          ),
        })} />
      <DirectStack.Screen name="C" component={C} />
      <DirectStack.Screen
        name="AddList"
        component={AddList}
        
      />
    </DirectStack.Navigator >
```

default when the first load the screen I am at `CList`  and on right button press I navigate to the `AddList` screen  and from `AddList` screen I navigate to `C` screen
till now everything is fine but when I press the back header button from the `C` screen I want to navigate to the initial screen that is `CList`.

currently, when I press the back header button from the `C` screen I navigated to the `AddList` screen  which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by pop all screen the stack by calling `navigation.popToTop()`

Also refer this [popToTop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#poptotop)